# Replacing negative components of a matrix with zeros

Tags: matrix, replacement

How can I replace the negative components of a matrix with zeros?

Comment: Clip[m, {0, Infinity}]

Comment: `m /. _?Negative -> 0`

Comment: @bills  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Edmund Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yet another alternative to introduce another function: `m UnitStep[m]`.

Comment: @Xavier Why not make it an answer? It's an amusing but also illuminating method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Gathering the answers given in the comments.*

---

• [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html):

```
Clip[m, {0, Infinity}]
```

• [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
m /. _?Negative -> 0
```

• [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
Replace[m, _?Negative -> 0, {-1}]
```

• [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html):

```
m UnitStep[m]
```

• [`HeavisideTheta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html):

```
m HeavisideTheta[m]
```

• [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Max`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html):

```
Map[Max[0, #] &, m, {-1}]
```

*Example:*

```
SeedRandom[30]
m = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 2, 2}]

(* {{{-6, 7}, {0, -7}}, {{-3, 1}, {-5, 10}}, {{3, 4}, {-4, 0}}} *)

Clip[m, {0, Infinity}]

(* {{{0, 7}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}, {{3, 4}, {0, 0}}} *)

SameQ[Clip[m, {0, Infinity}], 
      m /. _?Negative -> 0, 
      Replace[m, _?Negative -> 0, {-1}],
      m UnitStep[m],
      m HeavisideTheta[m],
      Map[Max[0, #] &, m, {-1}]
]

(* True *)
```

Comment: One more: `Map[Max[0, #] &, m, {-1}]`.

Comment: `Replace[m, _?Negative -> 0, -1]`

Comment: which one is fastest?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. `m UnitStep[m]` is the fastest